# How to redirect referrer page to test.html via htaccess?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect anyone who is coming from **domain.com** to **test.html** using htaccess.

Also I have WordPress site, is any plugin for this?

I searched and found this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERRER} !^http://my.domain [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?first-page.HTML$ http://reffered.domain/ [L,R]
```

but it didn't work for me.

Have I made any mistakes in htaccess? I am new to htaccess.

Would you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/test.html [L,R]
```